# How do I add mysqli_fetch_assoc array to preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this problem that I cannot figure out. It seems to be very simple, but it simply doesn't work. Here is the code in Php.

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$title[] = "'/".($row["Name"])."/'";
$content[] = $row["Content"];

}

$arr2 = implode(" ",$content);
$replace= "some text"; 
echo preg_replace($title, $replace, $arr2);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the quotes you're putting around `$row['Name']` - don't think that's valid regex syntax, as your `$title` will contain values like this:

```
Array( 
    [0] => "'/yourvalue/'",
    [1] => "'/yourvalue/'",
    [2] => "'/yourvalue/'"
)
```

Try:

```
$title[] = '/' . $row["Name"] . '/';
```

...then your array values will be:

```
    [0] => "/yourvalue/"
```

**--edit--** Why don't you try doing your replace during your loop, this way you'll be replacing one instance each time instead of every instance at the end.

```
<?php

$replace = "some text";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $content[] = preg_replace('/' . $row['Name'] . '/', $replace, $row["Content"]);

}

$arr2 = implode(" ",$content);
echo $arr2;

?>
```

Comment: Umm. Thanks, but still not working :(. I am trying to make the array created from the fetch be the array that is used to find the text.